# Как спрятать view при нажатии, и при последующем запуске Fragment?

Tags: java, android

у меня есть информационная карточка CardView_attention, где есть кнопка Button_attention, мне надо что бы при нажатии на кнопку, карточка скрывалась (visibility.GONE) и при последующем onCreateView она не отображалась, если кнопка уже была нажата

Все это происходит во Fragment, если это так важно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать при помощи [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). При нажатии на кнопку впервые вы будете записывать данные в память устройства. Например так:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PERSISTANT_STORAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("clicked", true).apply();
```

Дальше в функции `onCreateView()` при повторном запуске вы будете проверять есть ли данная переменная в памяти устройства:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PERSISTANT_STORAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.getBoolean("clicked", false);
```

и дальше можно сделать простую проверку получаемой переменной:

```
if(settings.getBoolean("clicked", false)){
}
```

таким образом вы сможете скрывать и показывать данное view в зависимости от значения хранящегося в памяти. [Вот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) туториал по работе с найтройками.

Comment: Правда, мне кажется лучше хранить не 0, 1, а Boolean. 0, 1 провоцирует думать, что есть ещё какие-то состояния

Comment: @СергейБувака, полностью поддерживаю :) Спасибо за замечание, исправил ответ :)